# Display message when data type of a data in a column changes in Jtable

Tags: jtable, comparison, abstract-data-type

I have a jtable with 4 columns and 4th column is editable and it contains integer values. I want to display a message box when user enters a string value in that column instead of integer values.

I have tried using `table.getColumnClass(3)` as follows but it is only showing a red border on the cell being altered. I want to display a message box saying "Please enter Numeric Value".

```
public Class getColumnClass(int col) 
{ 
    if (col == 3)
    {
        return Integer.class;
    }
    else 
    {               
        return String.class;
    }
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Can anybody please suggest something about this question

Comment: Anybody please advise something

Comment: Hey, Have anybody got something for this.